# Error widh PostUpdate

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

when I add *** * @ORM\PostUpdate() and @ORM\PostUpdate()** together , I have this error **:**

FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function guessExtension() on a non-object

and if I remove **@ORM\PostUpdate()** it work but update photo don't work

```
    private $tempFilename;

/**
* @ORM\PostPersist()
* @ORM\PostUpdate()
*/
public function upload()
{
    // Si jamais il n'y a pas de fichier (champ facultatif)
    if (NULL === $this->image)
    {
        return;
    }

// Si on avait un ancien fichier, on le supprime
if (null !== $this->tempFilename) {
  $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->tempFilename;
  if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
    unlink($oldFile);
  }
}


// On garde le nom original du fichier de l'internaute
$name = $this->slug.'.'.$this->image->guessExtension();

// On déplace le fichier envoyé dans le répertoire de notrechoix
$this->image->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $name);

// On sauvegarde le nom de fichier dans notre attribut $url
$this->image = $name;
$this->url =  $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$name; // retourne le chemin web du fichier qui lui peut être utilisé dans un 
                                               //template pour ajouter un lien vers le fichier uploadé

//$this->url = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$name  :  retourne le chemin absolu du fichier

}


//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using non-strict comparision:

```
if (NULL == $this->image)
{
    return;
}
```

Because your $image variable might be set to empty string (or something like that).